# AES authoritative recommendations?

Tags: aes

I am trying to figure out if there is an authority like FIPS, NIST, NSA, or DOD that has recommendations or standards for implementing AES such as key derivation algorithms and iterations as well as CSPRNG for keys but I can't seem to find anything. Is there any authoritative documentation for "current" AES implementations?

Answer (score 2):

For key derivation functions, NIST has https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-108r1.pdf (which supports AES-based CMAC as the underlying PRF - however the document does recommend using HMAC or KMAC instead).

Now, this is not meant to be a password based kdf (that is, it is designed to process the shared secret from a Diffie-Hellman or a KEM, rather than a low entropy password); I don't know of any AES-based recommendations for that.

As for a CSPRNG, NIST has https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-90a/rev-1/final which includes the AES-based CTR_DRBG

Comment: Thanks a lot. So is it fair to say that NIST sets the "standard" for aes implementations' parameters?

Comment: Well, if you're specifically asking about FIPS standards, NIST pretty much sets those...